# Where does Jesus Say He is God?

Tags: life-of-jesus, bible, christology

- Many parts in the bible where he said he can't do anything by himself, but by the will of God.
- If you look at the sentences above almost all the prophets before him used the same words.
- When he said son of God or my father, almost all prophets before him used the same word, because in some parts of the bible it mentions children of God. That means we are his brother and God is our father, I don't think that means we are really his children; it means we are servants and if we are servants, then Jesus too was a servant of God.

Comment: "**when he said son of God ... almost prophets before him used the same word**" - Which prophet referred to himself as the son of God?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Please consider taking the [tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and seeing [how we are different to other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites?s=1|1.9119) in order to understand how you can contribute effectively here.

Answer (score 1):

> And Thomas answered and said unto him, My Lord and my God. Jesus saith
>   unto him, Thomas, because thou hast seen me, thou hast believed:
>   blessed are they that have not seen, and yet have believed. (John 20:28)

Besides no one of the prophets before Jesus ever said something like this:

> Have I been so long time with you, and yet hast thou not known me,
>   Philip? he that hath seen me hath seen the Father
>
> Believe me that I am in the Father, and the Father in me (John 14:9-11)

, which, if not true, would have been a blasphemy.